# Can't show message on keydown of the edit

Tags: delphi

Is this bug or I'm missing something out?

This is code written in Delphi XE2, but it doesn't work in XE3...

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin

  if Key = VK_ESCAPE then //works when I press ESC!
    ShowMessage('escape');

  if Key = VK_RETURN then
    ShowMessage('enter'); //doesn't work when I press ENTER!
end;
```

Comment: The code shown above *should* work. It works in Delphi 2009, and I can bet almost anything that it still works in Delphi XE3. There is something else wrong in your particular project, which is not shown above. Surely, if you create a new, empty, VCL project, add a `TEdit` and insert the code above, then it will work.

Comment: If you have a button on the form with it's default property set to true, the enter key is directed to the button.

Comment: @LU RD That's it, I unchecked default property of the form and it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The ENTER key is considered a "Dialog Key"; it could, for example, activate the default Button on a form. It's not a bug, it's just the way things are. If you want the `TEdit` to receive the `ENTER` key you need to subclass it in order to handle [WM_GETDLGCODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and say you want to receive the `ENTER` key. You would need to do something like this:

```
procedure TYourEditSubclass.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  Message.Result := DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
end;
```

Alternatively you could enable [KeyPreview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.KeyPreview) on the FORM and use it's keyboard events. When you receive the Enter key, test if the Edit has the focus or not. Something like this would work:

```
procedure TForm6.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_RETURN) and (Edit1.Focused) then
    ShowMessage('enter');
end;
```